# how to check if a field in one file does not contain list of values from another file in UNIX

Tags: unix-text-processing

I have two files, one has the data that is transactional value for that column. Suppose currency code and the another file has the valid/expected currency code.

File1 :

ID|col1|curr_cd

1|abc|INR

2|def|USD

3|xyz|3AB

4|tuv|ABC

....

File2

curr_cd

INR

USD

CAD

....

I need the list of values those are invalid, which means is present in File1 but is not present in File2. File1 may contain millions of transactions, so I need an AWK or a command that could give me the result faster.

Can anyone help me here please.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Returns whole row
fgrep -vf file_2 file_1

# Returns just the bad value
fgrep -vf file_2 file_1 | awk -F '|' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 